# Mount google secret manager secret to KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer, google-secret-manager

I have a private Cloud Composer 1(Airflow 2) cluster. I can mount a GKE Secret as a file with KubernetesPodOperator. It gives me overhead of deploying secrets to Kubernetes directly, which I wouldn't prefer.

But I couldn't find a way to mount a secret from Google Secret Manager to KubernetesPodOperator.

Do you know how to mount Secret Manager secret to a KubernetesPodOperator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-gcp to mount secrets as files from Secret Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I didn't know this one.